# Parsing boolean input in java from command line.

Tags: java, parsing, boolean, command-line-arguments

Hi i need to read a `boolean` value from command line. I am new to java so after some basic search wrote the below code. The problem is if I use the `nextBoolean()` function, i get `inputmismatchexception`. So I had to write the `if` condition check and hardcode the value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Boolean Value: ");
    String value = s.nextLine();
    //Boolean myBoolVal = s.nextBoolean(); // Throws InputMismatchException if anything other than true/false is entered.
    Boolean myBoolVal = false;
    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || value.equals("1"))
    myBoolVal = true;
}
```

Assuming that `0` or `1` could also be `integer` type so `nextBoolean()` throws exception. So what is the best way to read a `boolean` input from command line in java.

Comment: When we evaluate a Boolean as a string we check to see that the first letter of the string is Y, y or 1 for true, anything else is false.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are only able to input text into the command line. The method `nextBoolean` only accepts the text `"true" and returns true` and accepts the text `"false" and returns false`. If you want to interpret the text "0" as false or "1" as true or "f" as false or "t" as true and so on then you have to write your own code as you've already done.